# How can I make VS Code IntelliSense for JS/TS import paths automatically add a trailing slash on directory/subdirectory suggestions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I know that when I import a directory in vscode, it loads the index file for that directory.

However, I don't use index files much in my next.js project.
so when I select a directory from intellisense's suggestions, I would like to see the next suggestion in that directory complete with 'app/folder/' instead of ending with 'app/folder', is this possible?

Currently, when I select a directory in intellisense, the autocomplete ends and nothing is displayed, so I have to keep typing '/', which is annoying.

Especially since I'm using absolute paths, not relative paths, so I'm typing '/' a lot.

I tried a few extensions, but it was hard to find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to do this. It was raised for discussion in the past, but that discussion hasn't had any activity in a while. See [when importing a module check if folder and add automatic forward slash
#25205](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25205). The reaon why it's not so easy/simple is precisely what you said: That different bundlers / runtimes can and will / can be *configured* to resolve directory imports in different ways, such as loading an index file. There are a lot of bundlers out there, and trying to parse their configuration and keep up with schema changes sounds like a nightmare.

Personally, I don't see the appeal or deep need for such a feature because `/` is already a trigger character in import path contexts. I.e. As long as you haven't changed the `editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters` setting, which defaults to `true`, when you type `/`, suggestions will automatically be triggered and the suggestion widget will appear.

If you're not satisfied with that, you should read the discussion in that issue ticket, and see if you think you have a better idea about how this should work (compared to the existing suggestions), and propose your idea there.

Comment: sincerely thank you for answer!